# Why does ghc in its own build pass contradictory optimisation flags?

Tags: optimization, compilation, ghc

I'm building a GHC from source again ([7.8](https://www.haskell.org/ghc/dist/7.8.4/ghc-7.8.4-src.tar.xz) on ARM, as there's no binary version of that), and noticed it does this at some point:

```
"inplace/bin/ghc-stage1" -static -optc-DTHREADED_RTS -optc-DDEBUG  -H32m   \
   -O -Iincludes -Iincludes/dist -Iincludes/dist-derivedconstants/header \ 
   -Iincludes/dist-ghcconstants/header -Irts -Irts/dist/build -DCOMPILING_RTS \
   -package-name rts -dcmm-lint   -i -irts -irts/dist/build        \
   -irts/dist/build/autogen -Irts/dist/build -Irts/dist/build/autogen    \
   -O2 -O0    -c rts/StgMiscClosures.cmm -o rts/dist/build/StgMiscClosures.thr_debug_o
```

Well, that's `-O`, `-O2` and `-O0` in a single command!

What is the reason for this, and which flag takes precedence anyway in such a case?

Answer (score 0):

`processArgs` processes command-line arguments left-to-right (see [`process` in `CmdLineParser.processArgs`](https://github.com/ghc/ghc/blob/ghc-7.8.4-release/compiler/main/CmdLineParser.hs#L171). Furthermore, the semantics of the `-O` flags is such that each of them turns on/off a certain subset of individual optimizations (see [`updOptLevel`](https://github.com/ghc/ghc/blob/f2b10f35a053e595fd309f523c5e93f619d2ec3a/compiler/main/DynFlags.hs#L2324)). So in your example `-O0` "wins" since it overwrites the effects of `-O` and `-O2`.

Comment: Ok. And the GHC build exploits this by using the command line as a sort of call-stack, shadowing unneeded, less specific flags without bothering to remove the preceding ones?

Comment: It seems so, yes.